# Get 'make html' to process jupyter notebooks with markdown instead of with restructuredtext

Tags: jupyter-notebook, markdown, restructuredtext, read-the-docs, nbsphinx

The github repo on which I work with many others contains many python files and about ten jupyter notebooks. 'make html' currently assumes that the markdown JN cells are written in reST, which can produce meaningless and ugly results. Is it possible to configure sphinx (or maybe nbsphinx??) so that readthedocs for the JN markdown cells is rendered using markdown (preferably in the JN flavour)?

There is a website https://gist.github.com/dupuy/1855764 that addresses this problem by discussing constructs that are common to markdown and reST, but the document is at least 10 years old. For example, it lacks the "click here" link construct that works in both markup languages, namely:

[click here](urlname).
There remain in our JNs constructs that do not seem to have a common syntax that produces decent rendering in both markdown and reST, or at least I have not been successful in searching for one. An example (and there may be others) is making nested lists, specially lists without numbers or bullets.

An alternative would be for the JN text cells to be rendered by reST. There is a website https://nbsphinx.readthedocs.io/en/0.8.8/raw-cells.html that explains how to use reST in a JN. I have two problems with that. Firstly, JNs in our environment do not behave as this website explains, and I do not know how to change our environment (configuration files for JNs??) to make them behave in the way claimed by the website. Secondly, our JNs are designed to be used by naive users (even more naive than I am), and so the JN must work when the naive user uses JN in its "out of the box" configuration.

Comment: First, have you seen [Myst](https://myst-parser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=jupyter%20book#find-the-right-documentation-resources) and Jupyter Book? Second -- It sounds like you are conflating some things. You should be able to take your Github repo & do whatever you want with it in parallel to what already happens with this system you mention. But you have to pay for & maintain those other options to serve it to your users unless you use a free service like MyBinder.org to access & share. Or a service that has a free tier.

Comment: Ten notebooks isn't a lot and so unless you are sharing with a huge audience you could probably get away with that. You may be better served by looking more into what you want to do, what the people your current system can/will accommodate and then post an updated version of this at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/). Whether you repo is public could factor into some of this. Some of the free/cheap services would need it to be public.